# Problems with Proxy in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, proxy, wireshark

I have a proxy in my clipse. The settings are all ok, it's the same proxy I have on Chrome.
When I debug my application and try to acess a webservice from my client's application, the proxy should let me through.
The problem is that there's no request being sent to the proxy. I've been monitoring the network traffic with WireShark and I see no request to the proxy when I debug my application.
When I open Chrome and the proxy asks for authentication, the request appears on WireShark.
Anyone has any idea why??
Tks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse proxy setting is just for Eclipse itself.

You need to explicitly configure your own applications to use the same proxy settings.